# Django2. Python vaiable in seperate file

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

Hello I'm doing a Python Django project and everything is going great so far!

I have a separate python file called number.py, and in that file I have a variable named "testvar". I can pass that to my index.html with views.py, but the random number in number.py is always the same when I reload the site and I need it to update everytime.

number.py

```
from random import *
testvar = randint(1, 100)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .number import testvar

testvar = testvar
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'porsche/index.html', {'testvar' : testvar})
```

And please tell me if there is a smarter way of doing this, thanks!

Comment: You should almost always avoid global variables (with the exception of settings) especially in servers. Even class level variables should be avoided if possible. method returns and parameter passing should be used where possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in number.py

```
def get_random_number():
    return randint(1, 100)
```

in views.py

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'porsche/index.html', {'testvar' : get_random_number()})
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use it directly in view as,

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from random import randint


def index(request):
    return render(request, 'porsche/index.html', {'testvar': randint(1, 100)})
```